# Draw multiple polygon on an picturebox

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a PictureBox, with an floor plan image.

On that image I would like to draw a polygon, which I can with the following code:

```
Private points As New List(Of Point)

Private Sub FlorPlan_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles FlorPlan.MouseDown

points.Add(e.Location)
FlorPlan.Invalidate(New Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 5, 5))
End Sub

Private Sub FlorPlan_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles FlorPlan.Paint
    For Each p As Point In points
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, p.X, p.Y, 5, 5)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myPen As Pen
    myPen = New Pen(Drawing.Color.Red, 2)

    Dim myGraphics As Graphics = PictureBox.CreateGraphics
    myGraphics.DrawPolygon(myPen, points.ToArray)
    'myGraphics.FillPolygon(Brushes.Red, points.ToArray)
    myGraphics.Dispose()
End Sub
```

What I would like to do is to get hold of that object, so that I later can change the background color, etc.

How should I proceed?

Comment: You need to either keep track of all the properties of each graphical object in a list of objects of some custom class, or else you need show each object as a new control, and have each control retain all those properties.  You can dynamically instantiate a new control each time another graphical object is needed.

Comment: @StevenDoggart 
How should i dynamically instantiate an new controle?
I have tried to create a new picturebox and then put the graphic in that, and added the new picturebox to the existing.

Is that the way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their are two ways this would typically be done:

- Manually keeping track of all your graphical objects in a list of some custom class.
- Dynamically load a new control for each graphical object.

If you choose to do the latter, I would recommend creating your own `UserControl` which contains all the necessary data about each graphical object, such as the points in the polygon.  To dynamically load them, you could do something like this:

```
Private Sub AddGraphicalObject(properties As GraphicalObjectProperties)
    Dim control As New GraphicalObjectControl()
    control.Properties = properties
    ' set position and size
    Panel1.Controls.Add(control)
End Sub
```

You will probably want to add some event handlers to some of the events on the control too as you add them.

Comment: How do i create a new controle, for storing that type of information?

Comment: Right click on your project, then in the context menu, select to add a new item to the project.  In the dialog window, select that you want it to be a user control.  For more info, search around the web--I'm sure there are some great tutorials on other sites.  If all you need is a picture box, you can just drag a picture box control to your user control in the designer, and then set it's docking property to fill.